# Не могу пропинговать виртуальную машину с хоста и наоборот

Tags: virtualbox

VirtualBox версии 6.0.2 r128162.
Хост : Windows 7.
Виртуальная машина : Debian.
Изначально тип подключения для виртуальной машины был **NAT**. Интернет **работал**, но я так понимаю, с помощью него невозможно нормально взаимодействовать , а именно пинговать хост и другие виртуальные машины, так?

Перевела на сетевой мост, но в таком случае интернета на виртуальной машине вообще нет. ifconfig не выдаёт IP ipv4.

Пробовала тип подключения **виртуальный адаптер хоста** и в настройках виртуальной машины указав этот самый виртуальный адаптер, но в таком случае айпишник есть, но пропинговать google и хост не получается.

Какие действия нужно сделать, чтобы возможно было нормально взаимодействовать между виртуальной машиной и хостом ?

Comment: Я понимаю, что у Вас проблема, но мне кажется, что Вам все же нужно немного менее эмоционально изложить Ваши трудности. Вопрос, ИМХО, нужно переформулировать и вряд ли кто-нибудь кроме Вас это сможет сделать. Посмотрите правила форума, на тему, как формулировать вопросы.

Comment: Включите два адаптера, один NAT, второй Host-only. Предварительно нужно создать сеть в Host Network Manager

Comment: @Nick, да, спасибо Nick. Наконец-то нашла видос на YT - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8lv88gH_0SA. Ужас, столько мучалась с этим....

Answer (score 0):

Как сказал Nick, нужно было включить два адаптера, один NAT, а второй Host-only.

А не только Host-only.....

Предварительно нужно создать сеть в Host Network Manager.